# Access forms and sub-forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am building a database on MS 2003. I have one form which calls for a series of options. This form is based on the table "Categories" which is linked to the main table by Customer ID.

Now, both forms appear together on the same screen, what I am trying to do is have the person select one or more of the categories and in pressing a command button then those categories which were selected will show its respective forms. The forms are invisible until selected and until the command button is pressed.

Since they are two different forms (categories in one) and the entry form on another, How do I program the command button to make the entry form visible FROM the other form?

The sub-form is located in a tab. I dont want to show it as a pop-up but to become visible within the tab where it's located

Comment: Alex, I recommend you change the title on this post. You can't expect to get much help with a title like that. Also, if one of the answers below helped you find a solution then you should accept than answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is open but invisible then you can refer to it as a member of the forms collection and make it visible:

```
forms("myForm").Visible = true
```

If the form isn't open then get its name from the AllForms collection of the project and then use the OpenForm method:

```
docmd.OpenForm currentproject.AllForms("myForm").Name, acNormal
```

Comment: The situation I have is that the sub-form is embedded in a tab, meaning I have different tabs for each category and it is invisible in the tab. SO I want a button on another form make the sub-form visible. Not as a pop-up but within the tab.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question but isn't that just a c ase of selecting the tab and setting the subform visible. Something like:

`Me.tabDetails.SetFocus`

`Me.subDetails.Visible = True`

Comment: Thank you.There is a form called Catagories located on the left side of the screen, on the right side on a TabControl with many pages there is a tab for each category, each has its own form. The form on the right side (under the tab) are invisible, I want to have the user select (check) on the index a category (one or more) and then clicks a command button and based on what he selected the respective forms on the right side become visible. Since they are two different forms, the code is not finding it, meaning I can't write "me.bla form.visible=true". Any help would be fantastic

Comment: If you want to refer to something on a different form then "me.blaform" won't work because "me" only leads you to the collection of things on the current form. The forms collection gives you a reference to every open form: `forms("blaForm").visible = True`

Comment: It must be my bad luck. It won't read it. It says it can't find it. Is there a way to connect the forms or add it?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudologic: you are basically going to want to set the Visible property with all of your forms to False during the form's Open event. You should place this Visible = False code in a separate subroutine so that the code structure can be called during other events too. (For example you may want to provide a Reset button so that the user can reset the form, or trigger the "set false" code when a new customer id is selected.) Then with every selected category you would set its associated form property visible by setting Visible = True.